# autocomplete to ui.item.url (outside of iframe window)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I'm loading an autofill search bar within an iframe on a website.

**Such as:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        source: [
             { value: "aloha mrhand", url: '/?partytime_id=2360' },
```

Problem is urls open within iframe tab.

I have tried base target attributes in both the iframed URL as well as the area the iframe is coded in. But didn't work. How could I edit this in jQuery to open in, ideally; the browser window as naturally, but if I must then a new window.

How to specify `target=_parent` within below:

```
     { value: "aloha mrhand", url: '/?partytime_id=2360' },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    // window.location = ui.item.url;
    if (window.location != window.parent.location)
    window.parent.location = ui.item.url;
}
```

Boom. (if anyone else runs into this, this what solved it)